# Binomial model with glmmTMB library

Tags: glmmtmb

I proposed the following binomial model, with the glmmTMB library, because I want to evaluate if there are differences between the proportions of infection by a given parasite for different communities, the number of dogs in the environment and, as a random effects variable, I propose the families, which are nested in each community. I would really appreciate it if you could tell me if what I am proposing is logical or if it has some error, or if you suggest me another library to analyze response variables that are proportions, together with explanatory variables of random effects. Perhaps the best is glmmTMB. What do you think?

Thank you very much for your time and your willingness. Now yes, the model proposed and greeted by R is the following:

#script
m1 <- glmmTMB(prop ~ comunidad + n.perros + (1|familia), weights =cabras.totales, data = cari, family = binomial)[image]

Comment: Hi Elisa. Welcome here. As I cautioned you at your earlier post too, please refrain from asking the same question again. Since you edited your earlier post, it would go to reopen review queue and the community would check whether the newly added info warrants the post to be answerable. Best wishes.